# Как из динамического многомерного json объекта вывести пары ключ->значение?

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия, динамические-массивы, итераторы

Есть *json объект* с многомерной вложенностью получаемый с сервера по **RestApi** вида

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "city_id": 1,
      "city_name": "Москва"
      "regions": [
       {
         "reg-1": 1,
         "reg-2": 2,
         "reg-5": 5
       }
      ],
    },
    {
      "city_id": 2,
      "city_name": "Волгоград"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
  "image": {
    src: "",
    width: "",
    height: "",
    alt: ""
  }
}
```

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы

1. составить перечень блоков с характеристиками в формате `ключ->значение` вне зависимости от вложенности (вложенность может быть любая)
2. при совпадении ключа с `image`, вывести в блоке изображение

На текущий момент с помощью рекурсии и итератора у меня получилось вывести все характеристики на первом уровне вложенности,  а вот с многомерность пока не могу разобраться..

```
function getData($query = '') {
$arr = array();
$brr = array();
        if($response) {
            $json_array = json_decode($response, true);
            function traverseStructure($iterator) {
                while ( $iterator -> valid() ) {
                    if ( $iterator -> hasChildren() ) {                
                        traverseStructure($iterator -> getChildren());                   
                    }
                    else {
                        $brr[$iterator -> key()] = $iterator -> current();
                    }
                    $iterator -> next();
                    
                }
                return $brr; //на этом уровне получаю все пары ключ-значения                
            }
            foreach($json_array as $obj)
            {
                $iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($obj);
                array_push($arr,traverseStructure($iterator)); // а здесь уже идёт заполнение массива только первым уровнем пары ключ->значение - почему?
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>There is an error in searching</p>";
        }
   return $arr;
}

$query_arr = getData($query); 
if(sizeof($query_arr)) { 
 foreach($query_arr as $item => $item_count) { 
   echo '<div>'; 
   foreach($item_count as $key => $value) { 
      echo '<p><strong>'.$key.'</strong> = '.$value.'</p>'; 
   } 
   echo '</div>'; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция array_walk_recursive в помощь

```
<?php
$result = [];

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    if(!is_array($item)){
        echo "$key - $item\n";
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```